# Saving one-to-many relationship CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, one-to-many, nsmanagedobject

I am having troubles with the relationship I have setup in CoreData. Its one to many, a **Customer** can have many **Contact**, these contacts are from address book.

My model it looks like this:

```
Customer <---->> Contact
Contact  <-----> Customer
```

*Contact.h*

```
@class Customer;

@interface Contact : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) id addressBookId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Customer *customer;

@end
```

*Customer.h*

```
@class Contact;

@interface Customer : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *contact;

@end

@interface Customer (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addContactObject:(Contact *)value;
- (void)removeContactObject:(Contact *)value;
- (void)addContact:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeContact:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

And trying save with:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
Customer *customer = (Customer *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Customer" inManagedObjectContext:context];

[customer setValue:name forKey:@"name"];

for (id contact in contacts) {
    ABRecordRef ref = (__bridge ABRecordRef)(contact);
    Contact *contact = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contact" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [contact setValue:(__bridge id)(ref) forKey:@"addressBookId"];
    [customer addContactObject:contact];
}

NSError *error;

if ([context save:&error]) { // <----------- ERROR
    // ...
}
```

With my code, I have this error:

```
-[__NSCFType encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9c840c0
*** -[NSKeyedArchiver dealloc]: warning: NSKeyedArchiver deallocated without having had -finishEncoding called on it.
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9c840c0'
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: How is `addressBookId` configured in your data model? What Core Data type are you using? Does Contact.m have any custom setter code for this attribute?

Comment: One possibility is that your setting a different type of `value` property compared to the one declared on your data model

Comment: @TomHarrington Contact.m don't have any custom code. And `addressBookId` in data model is `Transformable`.

Comment: I am not sure you can bridge the ABRecordRef to an object like that. There is no object representing a Contact in the AddressBook. I suggested creating your own object, or simply saving the ABRecordRef id as a number in CoreData, and reading it from AB whenever you need it. Any object saved into CoreData needs to support encoding, and again, I don't think that bridge is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `addressBookId` is (as you mentioned in a comment) defined as a transformable attribute on the `Contact` entity. However (as you also mentioned in a comment) you don't have any custom code to actually transform an `ABRecordRef` into something that Core Data knows how to store. With no custom transformer, Core Data is going to try and transform the value by calling `encodeWithCoder:` on the value. But `ABRecordRef` doesn't conform to `NSCoding`, so this fails and your app crashes.

If you want to store the `ABRecordRef` in Core Data, you'll need to create an `NSValueTransformer` subclass and configure that in your data model. Your transformer would need to convert `ABRecordRef` into one of the types Core Data knows. I haven't worked with the address book API enough to advise on the details of this, but Apple documents `NSValueTransformer` pretty well.

The fact that it's a one-to-many relationship is irrelevant; the problem is that `ABRecordRef` can't go into your data store without some transformation.